# Is it possible to test the converse of the null and alternative hypotheses?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test

Consider a simple t-test.

Traditionally,

$H_{0} : \mu_{1}=\mu_{2}$

$H_{1} : \mu_{1}\ne\mu_{2}$

Is it possible to instead assume:

$H_{0} : \mu_{1}\ne\mu_{2}$

and test if:

$H_{1} : \mu_{1}=\mu_{2}$?

Random example:
a guinea pigs and giraffes are different heights. But a shrink ray can make them the same size. Does the shrink ray make every organism significantly the same size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NO**

Testing a null hypothesis relies on having some distribution of the test statistic under the null hypothesis. For example, when we do a t-test, we can show that, when the null is true, the test statistic has a t-distribution with some degrees of freedom.

When the null hypothesis is not an equals sign, we cannot specify a distribution of the test statistic under the null hypothesis.

However, you can do some kind of [equivalence testing where you use two one-sided tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_test#TOST_procedure) to put bounds on the extent to which a value differs from some theorized value. Perhaps $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are practically equivalent if they are within $0.1$ of each other, and you can test that they are.

Comment: *Testing a null hypothesis relies on having some distribution of the test statistic under the null hypothesis. <...> When the null hypothesis is not an equals sign, we cannot specify a distribution of the test statistic under the null hypothesis.* Yet we routinely run one-sided tests, e.g. one-sided $t$-test with $H_0$ covering one half of the real line. You may want to briefly explain how that is possible.